# C++ trigger if one word is present

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

Bellow is obvious. It finds the word we want in text, in this case "hi." Then it runs that bit of program.

```
std::getline(std::cin, text);
if(text.find("hi") != std::string::npos
{
/////thing1/////
}
```

The problem is if we were to type in "history is a subject"

```
std::getline(std::cin, text);
if(text.find("history is a subject") != std::string::npos
{
/////thing2/////
}
```

Both thing1 and thing2 will run because "hi" is present in both.

Is it possible to make a a requirement that makes ONLY "hi" what triggers thing1? Exactly "hi". Nothing else would have been typed. So if "history is a subject" was inputted instead, only thing2 will run. I hope that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: What about `if (check history) else if (check hi) else if (..)`

Comment: A classic case of not checking for delimiters. "hiya" triggers the first one too, as does "hickory".

Comment: If you want a useful answer, you need to explain what you want the rule to be. Do you literally want to match only exactly "hi"? Or do you want to match on anything that includes the word "hi"? Or what?

Comment: There will be a lot more if statements searching for certain words in what will be inputted. Some words contain "hi" in them like history, high or hiss so to check all the other words that might contain "hi" with else if is inconvenient. So yes, exactly "hi." Nothing else is typed.

Comment: If you only want to match exactly hi then `if (text == "hi")`

Comment: @Niel Kirk: That was it! Thank you.

Comment: MY NAME IS NOT NIEL. IT'S 4 LETTERS. WHY DO PEOPLE FIND IT SO HARD. I'm ok.

Comment: Might help http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/

Answer (score 1):

Run here:   http://ideone.com/T4f5g8

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string text = "hi";
    regex rgx(text);

    if(regex_match("history is a subject", rgx) == true)
        cout << "false"; // never gona print as rgx=hi 

    if(regex_match("hi", rgx) == true)
        cout << "Matched";

    return 0;
}
```

This is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Using `regex_match` there is quite a bit of overkill, but it certainly works. I would prefer the far simpler plain string-comparison though.

Answer (score -1):

i don't know much about c++ but i know with in c you could add a space after the hi: "hi ". It would look for a space after the "hi".

```
std::getline(std::cin, text);   
if(test.find("hi ") != std::string::npos)
{
     //thing 1
}
```

Comment: What if "hi" were the last word or only word?

Comment: It'd  also false alert if you get it "Chi " as input